# Illegal call of non-static member function with struct & wifstream

Tags: c++, winapi, struct, static

Alright so I am trying to use wifstream to read from my .txt and put into my structure. I keep getting issues with this code: Please tell me what I need to know about it and why its failing. Thanks <3

I have 8 errors and they are all:

```
std::basic_istream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::getline': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
std::basic_istream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::getline': illegal call of non-static member function
std::basic_istream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::getline': illegal call of non-static member function
std::basic_istream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::getline': illegal call of non-static member function
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::getline [with _Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>]" matches the argument list
```

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <fstream>

//SQL Headers
//Add SQL later with option to store games location.

//Macros Tab1
#define IDB_BUTTONLAUNCH 100
#define IDB_PROCESSCHECKBOX 101

//Macros Tab2
#define IDB_SQLRADIOBUTTON 201
#define IDB_NOTEPADRADIOBUTTON 202

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

int numberAdder = 0;
int *numberAdderPTR = &numberAdder;

struct gameSaved
{
    int gameID = 0;
    static wchar_t szGameDirectory[100];
    static wchar_t szApplicationName[100];
    static wchar_t szComboName[100];
};

wchar_t gameSaved::szGameDirectory[100];
wchar_t gameSaved::szApplicationName[100];
wchar_t gameSaved::szComboName[100];
gameSaved gameList[50];
```

---

```
void WndProc (etc) // This is just representing that it is all global.
{
            std::wifstream savedGames;
            savedGames.open(L"ComboBox Saved Games.txt");
             //Error Code is with all the std::wifstream::getline below
            while (std::wifstream::getline(gameList[numberAdder].gameID, 2))
            {
                std::wifstream::getline(gameList[numberAdder].szGameDirectory, MAX_PATH);
                std::wifstream::getline(gameList[numberAdder].szApplicationName, MAX_PATH);
                std::wifstream::getline(gameList[numberAdder].szComboName, MAX_PATH);
                ComboBox_AddString(hComboBoxTab1, gameList[numberAdder].szComboName);
                *numberAdderPTR = gameList[numberAdder].gameID + 1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* error message, as well as point out where in the code you get the error.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the heads up and edit.

Comment: `gameID` is an `int`, you cannot `getline` into it. Also, `MAX_PATH` isn't `100`, and you seem unaware that you have set up your class so that all saved games share a common directory, name and combo name? (Only the ID is separate for each save)

Comment: I just realized that, how do I change the save? I figured I could get by-by making an array of the structure and incrementing the value.

But as you said, the only real thing that changes is the ID and it saves over the rest. So do you have any tips? @M.M

Comment: Yes, don't make the members `static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getline` is a non-`static` member of `std::wifstream`. Hence, it is not legal to use:

```
std::wifstream::getline( ... );
```

You need an object to make the call.

```
std::wifstream input;
input.getline( ... );
```